# .split() method not working on ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to make a simple algebra calculator app on ruby, but I encountered a problem while coding it. The .split method, which I was using to divide the equation into "sections" (separated by plus and minus signs), did split the equation, eq, with + signs, but it didn't with - signs.

```
eq = gets.chomp
a = []
a = eq.split("+")

a.each do |n|
 case n
 when n.include?("-")
    a << n.split("-")
 end
end

print a[0], ";", a[1]
```

I used the case when because if I did not, it returned a NoMethod Error. I already made a regular calculator, so I thought this would made a good next-project. I was also wondering if you had any idea to make my code shorter; maybe by creating a method. Below is my regular calculator's code, which I would also like to know how to make shorter.

```
loop do
print
equation = gets.chomp

 if equation.include?"^"
    exponent_e = equation.split("^")
    result_e = exponent_e[0].to_f ** exponent_e[1].to_f
    print " = #{result_e} "
    puts
 elsif equation.include?"%"
    percent_e = equation.split("%")
    number = percent_e[0].to_f / 100
    result_p = number * percent_e[1].to_f
    print " = #{result_p} "
    puts
 elsif equation.include?"/"
    res_d = equation.split("/")
    result_d = res_d[0].to_f / res_d[1].to_f
    print " = #{result_d} "
    puts
 elsif equation.include?"*"
    res_m = equation.split("*")
    result_m = res_m[0].to_f * res_m[1].to_f
    print " = #{result_m} "
    puts
 elsif equation.include?"+"
    res_a = equation.split("+")
    result_a = res_a[0].to_f + res_a[1].to_f
    print " = #{result_a} "
    puts
 elsif equation.include?"-"
   res_s = equation.split("-")
   result_s = res_s[0].to_f - res_s[1].to_f
   print " = #{result_s} "
   puts
 else
    puts "Input valid equation"
 end
end
```

Comment: Please let us know your expected behavior and the actual behavior. It's hard to fix "it didn't work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument passed to the `split` method will split up your string by the argument passed and return an array with everything else all split up.

For example:

```
"a+b".split("+")
#=> ["a", "b"]

"c-d".split("+")
#=> ["c-d"]

"c-d".split("-")
#=> ["c", "d"]
```

I would probably refactor the code by either using OOP creating a `class Calculator` and then creating the methods for each functionality (i.e. plus, minus, divide, etc..). This would make the code more readable and easier to maintain.

Another cool thing to consider is using metaprogramming.

```
def calculate(fxn, arr_numbers)
  if arr_numbers.size == 2
    arr_numbers.send(:reduce, fxn)
  end
end
```

Where `fxn` is a string (i.e. "+", "-", etc..), and `arr_numbers` is an array of 2 numbers, not strings (i.e. [2, 5])

You can expand this to take multiple numbers as well or add other functionality..